# C++ private member variables same name as ctor params

Tags: c++, constructor, scope, initialization, initializer-list

I know that many peoplpe use a prefix or suffix for private member variable names.  For those who don't, but just use the name - how do you initialize them if you want to have constructor params of the same name?

Comment: You can postfix a `_` to the parameter names.

Comment: Prefix members with `m_` or `s_` (for the statics)

Comment: You can use `this` to disambiguate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By simply writing them. The rules of the language prevent problems.

```
struct Foo
{
   Foo(int x) : x(x) {};
   int x;
};
```

Outside the `()`, only the data member is in scope; inside, the function argument *hides* the member just as it would in a normal function body:

```
int x = 2;
void foo(int x)
{
   // any access to `x` means the argument
}
```

This is one of many reasons that I do not use the `m_` prefix style (or equivalent) when naming data members.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to use a mem-initializer list. For example

```
class A
{
private:
   int data;
public:
   A( int data ) : data( data ) {}
};
```

If you want to use the data member within the constructor's body then there are two approaches to distinguish the data member and the parameter

```
class A
{
private:
   int data;
public:
   A( int data ) : data( data ) 
   {
        A::data    *= data;
        this->data *= data;
   }
};
```

Comment: Except now your member has three times the required value. Not a good job.

Answer (score 2):

You just initialize them in the initialization list:

```
struct foo
{
  foo(int bar) : bar(bar) {}
 private:
  int bar;
};
```

Note that the initialization list is the only way to explicitly *initialize* a member in a constructor. Once you're in the body of the constructor, the member has already been initialized.

As an aside, C++ allows you to initialize a member at the point of declaration, in which case it is initialized to that value unless otherwise initialized in the constructor:

```
struct foo
{
  foo(int bar) : bar(bar) {}
  foo() {} // bar initialized to 42
 private:
  int bar = 42;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use an initializer list, you can simply use the same name and the compiler will understand what you mean.

Example:

```
Book::Book(std::string title, int year) 
: title(title), year(year)
{}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method formal name is not of high value, considering how limited it's scope is.   And yet there *should* still be motivation to be able to instantly distinguish these items 'origins' at a glance.

It has become my practice to both

a) prefix my data attribute names with 'm_',

AND

b) prefix the method / function parameter names with 'a_' or 'an_', always striving for grammatical correctness.

```
LMBM::Node::Node(uint8_t a_max) : m_max (a_max) ...

void* LMBM::Node::threadEntry(void* an_objPtr) ...

void   DV1::processDirent(const std::string&  a_dirPath) ...

void   DV1::handleDT_REG (DV::Dirent*        an_ent,
                          const std::string& a_path) ...

FInfo (const std::string& aPfn, const int64_t& aFileSz) :
     m_pfn    (aPfn),
     m_fileSz (aFileSz) ...
```

Goal       - easier to read

Motivation - code is written once, read many times

I understand the special case for the ctor initializer list. But I am also confident that the use of prefixes (of your choice) do help prevent several kinds of mistakes that occur during development and maintenance.